# Problema double free en C

Tags: c, manejo-de-memoria, parser

Estoy haciendo una función que me coge una cadena de texto en C y me busca un '$' en cualquier posición y me sustituye el resto de la cadena hasta que encuentra un caracter que no cumple el formato `"%[_a-zA-Z0-9]"`.

El problema que tengo es que me salta un error `free(): double free detected in tcache 2`. He intentado de todo para resolverlo. Solo me salta este error con la memoria dinamica cuando la variable de entorno que solicito es larga, estilo si hago un `echo $PATH`.

Por si sirve de ayuda, tiene toda la pinta que tengo el error en el realloc. El doble puntero arg ya estaba reservado con memoria dinámica y se libera en otra función, el error está aquí seguro.

¿Me podrían ayudar a solventar este error?

El código:

```
int gestion_metacaracter_dollar(char** arg){
        char var_name[1024];
        char var_val[1024];
        char* subcadena;
        int desp_dollar;

        size_t var_len;
        size_t var_val_len;

        char* pos = strchr(*arg, '$');
        if(pos == NULL || *(pos + 1) == '\0') { return 1;}
        desp_dollar = pos - *arg;

        if(sscanf(pos+1, "%[_a-zA-Z0-9]", var_name) != 1) { perror("Error en el nombre de la variable"); return -1;}
        var_len = strlen(var_name);

        strcpy(var_val, getenv(var_name));
        if(var_val == NULL) { fprintf(stderr, "La variable $%s no existe\n", var_name); return -1;}
        var_val_len = strlen(var_val);

        *arg = (char*)realloc(*arg + desp_dollar, strlen(*arg) - var_len + var_val_len);  
        if (*arg == NULL) { perror("Error en realloc"); return -1; }

        strcpy(*arg + desp_dollar, var_val);
```

Comment: ¿Puedes escribir todo el código y qué haces para reproducir el problema? Así podemos depurarlo.